# Multi-Dimensional array outputs null

Tags: arrays, list, null

Okay so this will be a program that list students names and their test scores. I have it all figured out but one little thing. I have to lines that list the name of the student...then allows me to add another student to the list without the exact same name repeating. (see lines labelled 1 and 2)

line one collects the names from firstNameField and lastNameField which the teacher would input...and the second line would "go up one" for the array, to ensure the names don't repeat when another student is added.

Unfortunately...everytime another student is added it looks a little somethnig like this...

EXAMPLE:

Jane Doenull 65 76 45 89 Jane Doenull 65 87 45 76 
John Smithnull 65 76 45 89

You can clearly see the problem...."null" is there, plus is repeats the second name (Jane Doe)

So what should I do to prevent this?

public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

```
int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; //number of student (15) test scores (4 scores)
String[][] aryNames = new String[15][2]; //lists the names of students
int numOfStudents = 0; //starts off students from zero...
int marks = 0; 

int test1;
int test2;
int test3;
int test4;

public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
```

//GUI stuff...

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String currentList = studentListField.getText();

    //Collects integers from test1Field though test4Field
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    for (int x=0; x <= numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
        sb.append(firstNameField.getText()).append(" ").append(lastNameField.getText()); //(1)
        sb.append(aryNames[x][0]); //(2)
        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
            sb.append(" ").append(aryStudent[x][y]);
            studentListField.setText(sb.toString() + "\n" + currentList);
        }
        sb.append("\n");

    }
    numOfStudents ++;
}
```

**ADDED:**  So it appears  "sb.append(aryNames[x][0]); //(2)" is nothing significant, and without it no name repeats except it outputs as ... example

Mary Jones 56 76 56 87
John Smith 45 45 45 45 
John Smith 45 45 45 45

So it repeats the second name added twice.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the data into aryNames?

You initialize it:

`String[][] aryNames = new String[15][2]; //lists the names of students`

and then you use it:

`sb.append(aryNames[x][0]); //(2)`

But where was it populated? It is the only time your reference it, and it's right after you're appending the name. So you're getting  null

the   is from:

`sb.append(firstNameField.getText()).append(" ").append(lastNameField.getText()); //(1)`

But if `aryNames` never has any data put into it `aryNames[x][0]` will be null, hence the null being appended.

So I'd check where you're populating the `aryNames` array.

Comment: Ya, that was a thought for me but I waaaas hoping it wasn't too big a deal. How should I add the "data" to the aryNames so that it outputs correctly without any nulls or repeated names? Since the only reason why I created aryNames was so nothing was repeated.

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure how your application is supposed to work? How are you currently populating the `aryStudent` array? It looks like the names are coming from text fields, so unless you had a firstName and lastName text field for each of the student names I'm not sure if there is a good way to get the from the GUI.

Comment: I do have a text field for each first name and student name, called firstNameField and lastNameField.

Comment: Okay, I'm just trying to make sure that I'm understanding you correctly. Your example has 15 students, so are there 30 text fields (first name and last name for 15 students)? Or just 2 text fields?

Comment: 8 text fields in total. two fir the first and last names, 4 for inputting test scores

Comment: Okay, so if there are only two for the two parts of the names, I'm not sure how you would get all of the 15 names **from** those text fields, since there are only 2. Is there any other source you can get those names from besides the text boxes?